# Cannot inherit google.maps.Map V3 in my custom class (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to create a **custom javascript class** that inherits from **google.maps.Map** (V3 API).
Here's the code:

```
function MyClass(domElem, options){
    google.maps.Map.call(this, domElem, options);
    var custom_var = new google.maps.MVCArray();
    this.getCustomVar = function(){ return custom_var };
}
MyClass.prototype = new google.maps.Map;
MyClass.prototype.constructor = MyClass;
```

This code throws a console error like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
```

I've already tried to put this in setTimeout with 5 sec delay, but I think the DOM element is not the problem (Because it works when I do the same with pure google.maps.Map contructor).

Thanks...

Comment: doesn't the problem come from the line: MyClass.prototype = new google.maps.Map, because you construct it without any parameters?

Comment: Hi philipp, i don't think so, because I did the same with google.maps.Marker and google.maps.Polygon classes and it worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/base.js?r=2) is a correct way of inheriting 'classes' in javascript:

```
goog.inherits = function(childCtor, parentCtor) {
   /** @constructor */
   function tempCtor() {};
   tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
   childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
   childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
   childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
};
```

So you can try something like:

```
function MyClass(domElem, options){
   google.maps.Map.call(this, domElem, options);
   var custom_var = new google.maps.MVCArray();
   this.getCustomVar = function(){ return custom_var };
}
goog.inherits(MyClass, google.maps.Map);
```

Comment: `var inherits = function(childCtor, parentCtor) {
 /** @constructor */
 function tempCtor() {};
 tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
 childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
 childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
 childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
};
// Apply the inheritance
inherits(Marker, google.maps.Marker);` I get a referenceError google is not defined please help?